# MailApp: fetch rows instead of columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

In the script of the MailApp Tutorial of Google Scripts, I want to change from 'Fetch Column 1' to 'Fetch Row 1', in the section `for (i in data)`. Could someone explain me how to do that?

```js
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: You already have the row defined as `row = data[i];` just use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Modification of your code to use rows instead of columns:

Add Question to your watch list
In the script of the MailApp Tutorial of Google Scripts, I want to change from 'Fetch Column 1' to 'Fetch Row 1', in the section for (i in data). Could someone explain me how to do that?

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  //loop through all columns
  for (var i=0;i<data[0].length;i++) {
    var emailAddress = data[0][i]; // First row, column i
    var message = data[1][i]; // Second row, column i
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

You might have to modify your range, depending on the structure of your data. Methods like [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastcolumn) allow you to automatically find the last column with contents, rather than setting a manual limit.